# npm install not installing dependencies - just lock file

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I've never had any problems with getting `npm install` to work before, so am unsure what the issue is now?

I have tried running:

- `npm install`
- `npm install --save-dev`

The first time I let my IDE run it (PHPStorm) and it created the `node_modules` folder but nothing was inside of it.

Then I deleted that and tried to run it manually but all it did was create the `package-lock.json` file and nothing else, and the output was:

```
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN Invalid version: "1.0"
npm WARN www No description
npm WARN www No repository field.
npm WARN www No README data
npm WARN www No license field.

up to date in 0.087s
```

Now I've had those warnings before and they've never caused any issues.

My **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "**********",
  "version": "1.0",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.5",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.13",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^6.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I then ran `npm install --save-dev --loglevel verbose` and here is the output:

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Brett\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '--save-dev',
npm verb cli   '--loglevel',
npm verb cli   'verbose' ]
npm info using npm@5.5.1
npm info using node@v6.9.1
npm verb npm-session 24ddfff75bdd69e7
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\Brett\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb lock using C:\Users\Brett\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-822c9c4b46ec75df.lock for D:\******************\node_modules\.staging
npm verb unlock done using C:\Users\Brett\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-822c9c4b46ec75df.lock for D:\****************\node_modules\.staging
npm info linkStuff !invalid#1
npm verb linkBins !invalid#1
npm verb linkMans !invalid#1
npm info lifecycle undefined~install: undefined
npm info lifecycle undefined~postinstall: undefined
npm info lifecycle undefined~prepublish: undefined
npm info lifecycle undefined~prepare: undefined
npm verb saving []
npm verb shrinkwrap skipping write for package.json because there were no changes.
npm info lifecycle undefined~preshrinkwrap: undefined
npm info lifecycle undefined~shrinkwrap: undefined
npm verb shrinkwrap skipping write for package-lock.json because there were no changes.
npm info lifecycle undefined~postshrinkwrap: undefined
npm WARN Invalid version: "1.0"
npm WARN www No description
npm WARN www No repository field.
npm WARN www No README data
npm WARN www No license field.

up to date in 0.057s
npm verb exit [ 0, true ]
npm info ok
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, seemed that even though it was only a `WARN`, the issue was the `version.`

All I had to do was change it from `1.0` to `1.0.0` and it started working.

Comment: This really helped. Thanks!

Comment: Npm gets more and more infuriatingly broken as time goes on.

Comment: OMG.. what can i say.. so simple.. but difficult to fix